# Pip Whl naming conventions for git branches

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools-scm

I feel like I am doing something wrong.  We have some projects that produce pip packages in CI whenever we push a commit.  I am using setuptools_scm to produce a version number based upon the last tag.  I have two problems that I am struggling to solve.

Let's say we have a scenario where two developers are working in two different feature branches.  Whenever either of them commits their code, our CI produces a new pip package and pushes it to a development pypi server.  The version contains information about the previous tag and the commit hash, but it doesn't contain any information about the feature branch that produced it.  If I look at the pypi server I will see packages from both developers.  As far as I can see, I can't tell which packages came from which feature branch without significant effort.

If someone wants to test out the feature branch, then they need to figure out the exact version number produced by setuptools_scm - something like `package-0.1.dev41+gabcdef12`.  This is painful to communicate everytime someone pushes a new commit.  It would be nice if the branch name was somehow part of the version.  (Something like `package-0.1.branch.dev41+gabcdef12`  Then the user could do a `pip install package==0.1.branch` to get the latest from my branch.  But I see that this is not a valid version.)

I've looked at https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html and the various PEPs that it references.  The only place where I could reasonable put a branch name would be in the local section.  This would solve the first problem.  I could easily see which feature branch each package came from.  But it doesn't help me with testing out a feature branch.

I know that I could produce an alpha/beta/rc tag and use that.  But this doesn't map to their intended use.  An rc would normally have several commits from many feature branches that were merged since the last release, not a new rc for every commit on a feature branch.

I know that I'm not the only one using git and pip packages.  Since I can't find a solution to the problem, I worry that I might be thinking about it wrong.  Are there commonly used or standardized ways to handle these issues?

Answer (score 0):

For those who may come across this in the future, I think the best solution is to not package feature branches.  Pip allows us to install from a feature branch via `pip install git+${REPO_URL}@branch` syntax.  This syntax works on the command line, and requirements.txt files, and with tools like pip-compile.  The user can tie themselves to the head of a particular branch or a specific commit.

The syntax is not the easiest to remember, but it does a very effective job of allowing me to share a feature branch.  When I want to make a release, I can then tag the repo and create a package that is more publicly consumable.